# Loading words from a text file to a map in c++

Tags: c++, file-io, dictionary

I am trying to make a program which counts the times specific words appear in a text. The list of words will be in one text file, and the text will be in another. The words and the amount of words in the list is unknown. My plan is to make the word list into a map in a `map<string,int>name` style with the different words as the keys an then increase the value by one in the map.

Here is an example:

File.txt:

```
This is the text the program will analyze with the other file. Fun stuff.
```

List.txt:

```
the
other
normal
```

And the expected outcome when you run the program is:

```
name[the] = 3
name[other] = 1
name[normal] = 0
```

**The main problem I need help to solve is how to make a map from the words in a text file.** I can probably sort out the other stuff myself. I obviously cant show you any of my code because I need to sort this out before I can even start.

Also, this is not an assignment, so I am free to do it in any other way. Please tell if you know about a more efficient way to do this!

Comment: Is there a question in here besides "can someone do my homework for me?"

Comment: Would you show us at least a few lines of your code?

Comment: Consider using a `std::map<std::string, int> mymap;` preloaded with your wordlist file. From there, iterate over all strings in your actual input file, and for every word do a `mymap.find(word)`. If the result is not `mymap.end()`, then use the returned iterator to bump the count by one. When you're done, the map will contain only the words from your wordlist file and the associated counts of said-words from the input text. Note: it is actually easier to just count *all* words in the input file, but that doesn't address the end-game of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read a word from the *text* file.
2. Increment the map entry for that word
3. (repeat)

Then

1. Read a word from the *words* file.
2. Output the map entry for that word
3. (repeat)

Answer (score 0):

your_map.insert( std::pair( your_string, your_int ) );

If you don't have a lot of words, you might also consider using a multimap and then calling count:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/count/

Comment: I assume (hope?) the OP knows how to insert things into a map. I suspect he probably is stuck on the file reading part. But I could be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

A lot here depends on what percentage of your text file you expect to be in your words list. If you expect most words to be in the list, then @DrewDorman's solution should work quite nicely.

If you expect only a small subset of words to be in the list, it may be pretty wasteful though. In such a case, you probably want to insert the words from the list into your map first (with a count of 0), then as you read words from your text file, search for each in the map and increment the count if and only if an entry for that word already exists in the map.